# HTTP2 conflicting logs between puma and nginx

Tags: nginx, http2, puma

I'm confused by the different logs, one reporting http2, the other http 1.0.

I'm not sure which config file to cite. Or if it's a normal occurrence for puma's stdout redirect to show 1.0 for http version? Thank you.

###### nginx

```
==> /var/log/nginx/access.log <==
[10/Oct/2021:05:45:15 +0000] "GET /users/Ovbzv/quickrates/o5l05/payment/YabQ0/pending HTTP/2.0" 200
```

###### puma

```
==> app/log/stdout.log <==
[5626] 2604:a880:800:10::637:b005 - - [10/Oct/2021:05:45:15 +0000] "GET /users/Ovbzv/quickrates/o5l05/payment/YabQ0/pending HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.0826
```

Comment: You are looking at two different connections: 1. the connection between the client and nginx (the reverse proxy); and 2. the connection between nginx and Puma; ... in this specific case, each of these connections is using a different HTTP version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at two different connections:

1. the connection between the client and nginx (the reverse proxy); and
2. the connection between nginx and Puma;

In this specific case, each of these connections is using a different HTTP version, as indicated by the logs.

This is easily possible because HTTP/2 was specifically designed with some backwards compatibility in mind, allowing HTTP/2 to be converted to HTTP/1 when in need (and the same goes to converting HTTP/1 to HTTP/2).